# How to use string variable as Table name in SQL query

Tags: winforms, ms-access

Making a winforms application and I want the name of the table in my SQL query to be equal to a variable I have called `TreeCodeName`. This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string TreeNodeName = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString();
            if ((TreeNodeName == "BOOKS") || (TreeNodeName == "CARDS") || (TreeNodeName == "COMPUTERS") || (TreeNodeName == "CONSOLES") || (TreeNodeName == "DEVICES") || (TreeNodeName == "DONORS") || (TreeNodeName == "MAGAZINES") || (TreeNodeName == "MOTHERBOARDS") || (TreeNodeName == "OTHERS") || (TreeNodeName == "PARTS") || (TreeNodeName == "PERIPHERALS") || (TreeNodeName == "POWER_SUPPLY") || (TreeNodeName == "PROCESSORS") || (TreeNodeName == "RAMS") || (TreeNodeName == "SOFTWARE") || (TreeNodeName == "STORAGE") || (TreeNodeName == "TERMINALS"))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    string query = "select * From Table Where Title = @Title";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TreeNodeName);
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error   " + ex);
                }

            }
```

Whenever I try to test this, I run into an error that says there was a syntax error on FROM. Any way to salvage this?

Comment: update your query string to: `string query = $"select * From {TreeNodeName} Where Title = @Title";`

Comment: check also if you're passing the correct parameter here `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TreeNodeName);`. Doesn't seem like you're passing the `Title` of the item.